# VisualStudio 2013/2015 : Error Git Microsoft with submodule (the edit icon disappears)

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, git-submodules, visual-studio-extensions

In a repository I use another repository with GIT submodule.

With SourceTree all is working well, but with Microsoft GIT plugin in Visual Studio, when I modify a file in a submodule, the modify icon appears (check) but when I save the padlock icon reappears.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Issue 790028](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/790028) was closed as "Deferred" in 2013, and has not been updated since.

That should mean add/commit from within a submodule is not yet supported at the moment (mid-2016).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is time they put in their day extension !! especially when using GIT on TFS !!   No updates since 2013 !!

Comment: @PhilippeAuriou I agree. Submodule support still need improvement.